# VMWare server console in Linux

Tags: linux, firefox, ubuntu-10.04, vmware-workstation

I'm trying to access the VMWare console from firefox using the VMWare plugin. The problem is that it doesn't work on Firefox version 3.6.8. So how can I access the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use the console by installing an older version of Firefox and running that since it's compatible with the plugin.

Comment: see my answer. this could work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Around VMware ESX 3 they redesigned the client using .Net. At that point Linux support became basically non-existent; you can use the web browser interface and start/stop virtual machines from there, but the console just does not work.

Or, if there's a way, I'd like to hear about it. VMware's forums are also full of complaints from Linux/FreeBSD sysadmins.

Answer (score 0):

When first trying to access a VM’s console via the vSphere Web Client 5.0 (using Debian’s default firefox-y iceweasel browser) , it wants the user to download/install VMware-VMRC.x86_64.bundle , which has to be run as root.

The install soon presents a dialog for configuring firefox’s system-wide plug-ins directory, but presents a default of /usr/lib/firefox/plugins (or /mozilla-firefox/ ?), which does not work (for me). Changing that dir to /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins gets the VMRC console app working under debian-ish linuxes.

Winds up with mozilla/plugins/np-vmware-vmrc-e.x.p-422570.so